# Font is installed in font book, but bold does not work

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I've installed a font in the font book, but the bold format does not work. I see the bold in the font book. Also, the italic format does work.
How to fix it?
(I'm running on El Capitan).

Is there an option to reinstall the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end, it got very simple. I just recopied the fonts to the `Font Book` and let it fix itself automatically, and it solved the issue! The Bold mode is working again!

Answer (score 1):

Your font could be broken. Not likely if it worked before but at least it is easy to check as there’s a font validator built into Font Book. Please mark the font and select **File > Validate Font**.

If you receive warnings or errors there’s no built in repair tool, though. But then at least you know...

Comment: Also note that some applications allow you to *apply* bolding to a font (select word and tap command B) while others require that you select the bold version of the font from the font menu, essentially picking a different font.

Comment: @Tom E thanks for the tip. I get that all is ok with the font. Do you have another idea?

Comment: You could do a safe boot—press the shift key upon restart. Among other things this will clear the font cache. Please note that safe boot is for maintenance only so restart your Mac immediately into regular boot once safe boot has finished.

Comment: @TomE I did a normal restart and it didn't help. Is this safe boot different? Is there an option to clear the font cache without a restart?

Comment: @roi.holtzman: A normal restart doesn’t clean the font caches. And a reboot doesn’t cost much—it’s one small step for the Mac yet a giant leap for your usage ;-)

Comment: @TomE so a safe boot also didn't help... Any other ideas?

Comment: @roi.holtzman: Does the Font Book preview correctly display the bold face?

Comment: @TomE yes it does.

Comment: @roi.holtzman: Why don’t you create a new user account and test the font there. This helps you figure out if it’s a user-related or a system-related problem. Also, try it in TextEdit as well as in other applications—which you have done already, I’m sure…

Comment: @TomE Already tried in TextEdit. It doesn't work. Do you know if there's a way to re-install the font?

Comment: @roi.holtzman: Fonts aren’t really installed. They simply need to be copied into one of the `Library/Fonts` directories. If you “install” them using Font Book, they are checked and then copied, that’s it. So I’m more or less running out of ideas, besides trying another user or, if at all possible, another device.

Comment: @TomE it works on another machine! So do you think I need to delete the fonts and then copy them again to `Font Book`? (Will it mess up my documents?)